# Excel filter not showing any data

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Workbook which multiple worksheets, and today the filter stoped working in one of them (which is the main worksheet, so that´s not good).

I was able to filter yesterday, but when I opened the workbook today, I was no longer able to filter. The dropdown menu does no longer show any values of the column, that I try to filter in.

I copied all the data into a new worksheet and added the heading manually, but the filter is still not showing anything.

Does someone know, why it is no longer working?

Kind Regards: Elias

Comment: ¿What size is the file? Did you try recreating the whole workbook from zero? ¿any macro that might be interfering?

Comment: No, there is no macro that would access this workbook, and the filesize is  2 MB. Recreating the workbook would be really hard, cause there are around 10 worksheets, which are all linked with each other.

Comment: Are there no other filter applied in any column already?

Comment: No, no filters in the entire worksheet, and I can´t use a single filter in any column.

Comment: I just went through all the worksheets, and disabled all filters in all worksheets, and now it works again. I don´t know why. Anyway I am happy I can filter now, and thanks for helping me.

Comment: I just reopened the file, and it is broken again. I have to say, my mental health is suffering...

Comment: Transfered the data into an official Excel Table, now it works again...